# Continuously update Python script in NppExec console [Notepad++]

Tags: python, console, notepad++, nppexec

I write Python scripts with NppExec/Notepad++. How do I update my console window as each line of my Python code is executed? For example, the following timer script:

```
#!usr/bin/env python
import time
import threading

class Timer(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, seconds):
        self.runTime = seconds
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    def run(self):
        counter = self.runTime
        for sec in range(self.runTime):
            print counter
            time.sleep(1.0)
            counter -= 1
        print "Done."

if __name__ == '__main__':
    t = Timer(10)
    t.start()
```

When I run in this in a command prompt window, it live updates every second. But in NppExec console, it updates only after exit. Is there a way to get the NppExec console to behave as the command prompt and update continuously?

Comment: Simple answer. Took me way too long to find it!
http://superuser.com/questions/381942/stop-nppexec-from-trapping-console-output-until-program-finishes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All that needs to be done is invoke the `python -u` command to run the script, i.e. `python -u timer.py` instead of `python timer.py`

This prints output in unbuffered mode by default. For custom output flushing in more detailed programs, the `stdout` definition has to be [rewritten](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107705/python-output-buffering).

Answer (score 2):

Not familiar with how that particular console app handles output, but `stdout` is buffered by default, which is probably the issue here. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107705/python-output-buffering) for ways of disabling it.

Comment: Using a custom class to flush output every time print is called works perfectly fine. I used Dan's custom stdout class approach from the link above. Thanks a lot!